# ggplotly: log argument cancels axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I just discovered the newish ggplotly function that makes ggplot2 graphs into interactive plotly visualizations. This is great. But I also ran into an odd effect, possibly a bug.

If I use the log= argument to change the axis scales, the axis labels disappear. log="x" will cause the x axis label to disappear, log="y" will cause the y axis label to disappear, and log="xy" will cause both to disappear.

The same thing happens if I use scale_x_log10() and scale_y_log10() functions instead of the log argument.

Is there a workaround for this?

Example (y axis label is visible, x axis label disappears):

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(cyl), log="x")
ggplotly()
```

or

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(cyl)) + scale_x_log10()
ggplotly()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get axis names if you supply them as arguments to `scale_...` function.

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(cyl)) + scale_x_log10("wt")
ggplotly()
```

Comment: This puts the variable names on the axes, which is good. But it still ignores axes labels (xlab="weight" or + labs(x="weight")).

Comment: Although this puts labels on the axes, the axes are no longer logged once converted to plotly. Or maybe the axes now show the exponent for the relevant power of 10--which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

or maybe this?

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = log10(wt), y=mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous("wt, log10-scaling")

ggplotly()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_trans(y="log10")
ggplotly(gg) %>% layout(yaxis = list(type="log", autorange=TRUE))
```

[image]